# How to extract a certain boundaries of a countour plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, extract, interpolation

Considering the countour plot provided by the following code:

```
# input data x,y,z:
x<-rep(c(1:100),times=10)
y<-rep(c(1:10),each=100)
z<-NULL
for(i in 1:10){
  n<-sample(c(10:30),1)
  m<-sample(c(50:70),1)
  z<-c(z,c(1:n,sample(c(50:100),100-m-n),c(m:1)))}

# bilinear interpolation of irregular data:
library('akima')
interpo<-interp(x=x,y=y,z=z,xo=seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=1000),yo=seq(min(y),max(y),length.out=1000))
image(interpo)

# convert data format for ggplot:
x<-rep(interpo$x,times=1000)
y<-rep(interpo$y,each=1000)
r<-NULL
for(i in 1:1000){
  r<-c(r,interpo$z[,i])
}
plo<-data.frame(x,y,r)

# plot the countour plot:
library(ggplot2) 
library(scales)
ggplot(plo, aes(y = y, x = x,  fill = r)) +
  geom_raster()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red",limits=c(min(r),max(r)))
```

The plot is something like this:
[image]

Now my question is:

Using R, is it possible to extract and visualize some boundaries (e.g. r=70) inside which the `r` value are larger than 70?

It would be best if the specific locations(x and y coordinate values of z(x,y) no less than 70) of the boundaries can be derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure about your expected output (it will be good if you add some), but the following may be close:

```
# visualize the points where r = 70
ggplot(plo, aes(y = y, x = x,  fill = r)) +
  geom_raster()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red",limits=c(min(r),max(r))) + 
  geom_point(data=plo[plo$r == 70,], col='white')
```

[image]
or

```
# visualize the points where r > 70
ggplot(plo, aes(y = y, x = x,  fill = r)) +
  geom_raster()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red",limits=c(min(r),max(r))) + 
  geom_point(data=plo[plo$r > 70,])
```

[image]

If we want to get the data back (from `ggplot`) for which `r > 70` we can try the following to:

```
p <- ggplot(plo, aes(y = y, x = x,  fill = r)) +
  geom_raster()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red",limits=c(min(r),max(r))) + 
  geom_point(data=plo[plo$r > 70,])

pg <- ggplot_build(p)
str(pg)
head(pg$data[[2]])
# fill        x y PANEL group shape colour size alpha stroke
#1 #E50056 26.96396 1     1    -1    19  black  1.5    NA    0.5
#2 #E70052 27.06306 1     1    -1    19  black  1.5    NA    0.5
#3 #E70050 27.16216 1     1    -1    19  black  1.5    NA    0.5
#4 #E8004F 27.26126 1     1    -1    19  black  1.5    NA    0.5
#5 #E9004D 27.36036 1     1    -1    19  black  1.5    NA    0.5
#6 #E9004C 27.45946 1     1    -1    19  black  1.5    NA    0.5
```

Another attempt with `dplyr`:

```
data <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)
dim(data)
#[1] 1000000       3
library(dplyr)
data <- plo %>% 
  inner_join(data, by=c('x'='x', 'y'='y')) %>% 
  filter(z >= 70 & r >= 70) # change the filter condition if needed
dim(data)
#[1] 10058     4
ggplot(plo, aes(y = y, x = x,  fill = r)) +
  geom_raster()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red",limits=c(min(r),max(r))) + 
  geom_point(data=data)
```

[image]

Comment: I think the 2nd plot is what I want. But I'm confused with the `dplyr` method. Using `data <- plo %>% 
  inner_join(data, by=c('x'='x', 'y'='y')) %>% 
  filter(z >= 70 & r >= 70)` the `x y r` represent the location and `r` value of the points. But what does `z` mean? `z` are the initial 1000 values before interpolation. Why its number becomes 10058 (in this case) and makes the 3rd plot differes from the 2nd plot?

Comment: I guess `z` is your actual and `r` is your fitted ( interpolated) coordinates and you want the filtering condition on both

Comment: Before `data <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)`, `x` and `y` are of length 1000*1000 (after interpolated) while `z` (initial observation) is of length 1000. I think `data.frame()` copy `z` in order to make them composable but these copied `z` values do not correspond to the `x y`. So I think   `data <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, r=r)` and `filter(r >= 70)` would be OK. Thanks for your marvelous help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `geom_density_2d()` to help with the visual aspect of your question. I used `data.table` to prepare the data as follows:

```
 library(data.table)

    plo2 <- data.table(plo)
    more <- plo2[r>=70]
    more2 <- plo2[r==70]

  ggplot() +
    geom_raster(data = plo, aes(y = y, x = x,  fill = r))+
    scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red",limits=c(min(r),max(r)))+
    geom_density_2d(aes(more$x,more$y), color = "black", size = .68)+
    geom_point(aes(more2$x,more2$y), color = "white")
```

[image]